# Org mode error when exporting ditaa figure

Tags: java, emacs, org-mode

I'm using org-mode 8.2.5h and java 7u6 on Mac OSX running 10.9.3 and having terrible problems trying to get org-mode to export a ditaa figure. I know I've had this running in the past, but now it's broken and beyond my knowledge to fix.

As a minimal example I've been trying

```
#+BEGIN_SRC ditaa :file ditaa-seqboxes.png :cmdline -r -s 0.8
+------+   +-----+   +-----+   +-----+
| {io} |   | {d} |   | {s} |   | cBLU |  
| Foo  +---+ Bar +---+ Baz +---+  Moo +  
|      |   |     |   |     |   |      |  
+------+   +-----+   +-----+   +------+
#+END_SRC
```

If I export this within a LaTeX file from the org-file, the file ditaa-seqboxes.png is not created and I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.stathissideris.ascii2image.core.ConversionOptions.<init>(Lorg/apache/commons/cli/CommandLine;)V
at org.stathissideris.ascii2image.core.CommandLineConverter.main(Unknown Source)
```

Any assistance in trying to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By the way, the top line of the rightmost box is one dash too short.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Fedora 20.
The problem seems to be that ditaa is not distributed with org mode directly. There's a dedicated package for it and that package even supplies a nice script to run ditaa, but org mode is not adapted to that.

Solution: Simply use the complete, standard version of org mode

Quick & Dirty How-To for Fedora:

```
cd
git clone git://orgmode.org/org-mode.git
sudo cp -R ~/orgmode/lisp/* /usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/org/
sudo cp -R ~/orgmode/contrib /usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/
```

Not pretty, but it works for me now.

I think your problem might be something different, but it might work for you too with the standard version and I'm sure others with the problem I had will find this question too.